# How are Java threads name chosen?

Tags: java, multithreading

In my app I create some threads (ok a lot maybe, but there are never more than 10 active at the same time and they're not doing big work), and at the end of their executions (i join them all before i continue), since they are doing work in a loop, they will do that some number of time, but even tho they are all finished (joined) when I check their names the Thread-XXX is never reset so I wondered if it's normal, I initially thought that when a thread terminated it would decrement the XXX number, but this would add something maybe not that useful to do.

I've searched through javadoc but all I found was this statement:

> Every thread has a name for identification purposes. More than one thread may have the same name. If a name is not specified when a thread is created, a new name is generated for it.

So does someone know if it's normal that after Threads 1 to 10 end the following will be named 11 and +?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: also it's weird every time I write my question then I write Hello at the start but it's erased for some reason I can't add a line before the first one.

Comment: If you care about thread names at all, you need to name them yourself. It is quite likely that it is left up to the implementation how it wants to generate thread names if you do not specify them (meaning you won't find Javadoc for that).

Comment: How do you create  thread?

Comment: *"it's weird every time I write my question then I write Hello at the start but it's erased for some reason I can't add a line before the first one."* - Things like greetings, introductions, and "thanks in advance" are considered unnecessary, and are either removed automatically, or later by (human) editors.  (Think of this from the perspective of someone in the future who is *just* looking for a solution.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you let the JRE to choose the name (not passing the `name` parameter to `Thread` ctor), then just walk through its code:

`Thread#Thread()` code:

```
public Thread() {
    init(null, null, "Thread-" + nextThreadNum(), 0);
}
```

And then look at `Thread#nextThreadNum`:

```
/* For autonumbering anonymous threads. */
private static int threadInitNumber;

private static synchronized int nextThreadNum() {
    return threadInitNumber++;
}
```

You can see that `threadInitNumber` is a `static` memeber that never gets reset, so it will be ever increasing for the application run.

Answer (score 3):

If you create new Thread with:

```
Thread thread = new Thread();
```

The answer is yes, at least on the environment:

```
java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)
```

The source code shows it clearly:

```
public Thread() {
    init(null, null, "Thread-" + nextThreadNum(), 0);
}

private static synchronized int nextThreadNum() {
    return threadInitNumber++;
}
```

But this is not guranteed in the API, so if you do care about it, you can custom a thread factory. For example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;

public class DefaultThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {

    private static int threadInitNumber;

    private static synchronized int nextThreadNum() {
        return threadInitNumber++;
    }


    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        return new Thread("Thread-" + nextThreadNum());
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't care about their names else I'd have renamed them on my own, I just think long time ago when installed Eclipse I did install JRE but not jdk, so I don't have access to source code, I think it's time for me to install it because I could have accessed it without help then, sorry to bother you.